# Use WKWebView to open URL and handle button tap using Spotify API

Tags: swift, oauth-2.0, spotify, wkwebview

I have been using [this project](https://github.com/Peter-Schorn/SpotifyAPI) to authenticate with the Spotify API in an iOS app. There is also an example app [here](https://github.com/Peter-Schorn/SpotifyAPIExampleApp/tree/main). In this example app, it opens the system browser using `UIApplication.shared.open(url)`. I was wondering if instead of doing that a web view could be shown in the app. I do have that working using a WKWebView which looks like this:

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        let parent: WebView
        
        init(_ parent: WebView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            print("Done loading")
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> WebView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let prefs = WKWebpagePreferences()
        prefs.allowsContentJavaScript = true
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.defaultWebpagePreferences = prefs
        return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        uiView.load(request)
    }
}
```

What is currently happening is when the web view is shown, nothing happens when tapping the "Agree" button. For context this is what the Spotify authorization page looks like:

[image]

I guess my question is how can I know when the "Agree" button is tapped? Is there a `WKNavigationDelegate` function that I should be using?